# react-native apk cannot install in Kirin chip

Tags: android, react-native

Using react-native.

I have problem distribute android app, to Huawei Kirin 980 chip Android v9, it cannot be install, error message at "`There was a problem parsing the package...`", I am using `signing key`, I can install in 2 different phone with kirin chip, but not this phone which is located at `China`.

I use this to compile the APK:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

In the build.gradle:

```
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
```

Did I not including arm version to support it?